# Fineuploader limit to a single file

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I would like to limit the amount files that can be dropped in the bucket to just a single file. I discovered the validation directive and the itemLimit attribute. However, when I set that to 1, it really doesn't do anything. Here's the code that I use to create the instance of fine upload:

Thanks for the help!

```
                $(this).fineUploader({
                    request: {
                        endpoint: 'api/endpoint.php'
                    },
                    validation: {
                        itemLimit: 1
                    },
                    autoUpload: true,
                    text: {
                        uploadButton: 'DROP ASSET HERE',
                    },
                    debug: false
                })
                    .on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, response) {

                });
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  There is even a live demo of this on the homepage that works.  You will need to provide some more information.

Comment: If this is not working for you, then you are likely using a version of Fine Uploader that predates this feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `multiple: false,` to the code, this will limit to a single file.

Comment: can you set `multiple:3` to have a max limit of 3 ?

Comment: multiple accepted type is only bool https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#multiple